# Работа с inline-block

Tags: html, css

Как можно задать максимальное количество блоков в линии в этом коде, что бы не выполнялся перенос относительно ширины?:

```css
    .example {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <a href="#" class="example"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480302668644876291/593713454779727877/logo1_1.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="example"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480302668644876291/593713454779727877/logo1_1.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="example"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480302668644876291/593713454779727877/logo1_1.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="example"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480302668644876291/593713454779727877/logo1_1.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="example"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480302668644876291/593713454779727877/logo1_1.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="example"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480302668644876291/593713454779727877/logo1_1.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="example"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480302668644876291/593713454779727877/logo1_1.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="example"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480302668644876291/593713454779727877/logo1_1.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="example"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480302668644876291/593713454779727877/logo1_1.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="example"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480302668644876291/593713454779727877/logo1_1.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="example"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480302668644876291/593713454779727877/logo1_1.png"></a>
```

Comment: наверно такой опции нету, либо я новой какой то фишки не знаю, но как правило это скрыть всё что вылазиет